# Selectively exclude paths or filesystems from Linux disk read cache

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, zram

The Linux kernel uses unused RAM for disk read caching. This is generally a good idea. But is there a mechanism to selectively exclude certain paths or mounted filesystems from this cache?

ZFS for example offers the option of fine-tuning the cache with dataset granularity with the `primarycache` and `secondarycache` parameters. However this is the exception as OpenZFS on Linux bypasses the regular disk cache.

Common Linux filesystems like ext4 do not seem to offer a way of fine-tuning read caching behavior. Is this correct?

(Background: ext4 is employed on top of [zram](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/admin-guide/blockdev/zram.html) to provide compressed ramdisks. However the kernel additionally places the contents of these filesystems in the read cache, which is unnecessary and detrimental.)

Thanks!